# An error occurred during validation / An error occurred during update

Tags: xcode, swift3, cocoapods

I get this error when trying to upload or validate.

These are my log files for the validation error. please help.

Critical Log

```
2017-04-29 10:49:11 +0000 [MT] Failed to generate distribution items with error: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
2017-04-29 10:49:11 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
```

Standard Log

```
2017-04-29 10:49:10 +0000 [MT] Beginning distribution assistant for archive: app name, task: Validate
2017-04-29 10:49:10 +0000 [MT] Automatically selecting the only availaable distribution method <IDEDistributionMethodiOSAppStoreValidation: 0x7fd7dca944b0>
2017-04-29 10:49:11 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fd7dc85e290:'/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-04-29/appname 4-29-17, 1.43 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/appname.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-04-29/appname 4-29-17, 1.43 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/appname.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-04-29/appname 4-29-17, 1.43 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/appname.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-04-29 10:49:11 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fd7d63efde0:'/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-04-29/appname 4-29-17, 1.43 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/appname.app/game/Pods_game.framework'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-04-29/appname 4-29-17, 1.43 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/appname.app/game/Pods_game.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-04-29/appname 4-29-17, 1.43 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/appname.app/game/Pods_game.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-04-29 10:49:12 +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant
```

Verbose Log

```
2017-04-29 10:49:11 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fd7dc85e290:'/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-04-29/appname 4-29-17, 1.43 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/appname.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'>
2017-04-29 10:49:11 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fd7dc85e290:'/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-04-29/appname 4-29-17, 1.43 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/appname.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'>
2017-04-29 10:49:11 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fd7d63efde0:'/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-04-29/appname 4-29-17, 1.43 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/appname.app/game/Pods_game.framework'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by removing the folder name 'game' from Copy Bundle Resources!